# Create a type that can contain an int and a string in either order

Tags: haskell, types

I'm following this [introduction to Haskell](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/haskell/haskell-intro-html/goodies.html), and this particular place (user defined types 2.2) I'm finding particularly obscure. To the point, I don't even understand what part of it is code, and what part is the thoughts of the author. (What is `Pt` - it is never defined anywhere?). Needless to say, I can't execute / compile it.

As an example that would make it easier for me to understand, I wanted to define a type, which is a pair of an Integer and a String, or a String and an Integer, but nothing else.

The theoretical function that would use it would look like so:

```
combine :: StringIntPair -> String
combine a b = (show a) ++ b
combine a b = a ++ (show b)
```

If you need a working code, that does the same, here's CL code for doing it:

```
(defgeneric combine (a b)
  (:documentation "Combines strings and integers"))

(defmethod combine ((a string) (b integer))
  (concatenate 'string a (write-to-string b)))

(defmethod combine ((a integer) (b string))
  (concatenate 'string (write-to-string a) b))

(combine 100 "500")
```

Comment: `Pt` is a constructor of `Point a` data type; i.e. a function `a -> a -> Point a` taking two values of type `a` and wrapping them in `Pt`. `data` declarations feel quite natural to me: on the LHS you give name (and parameters, if any) and on the RHS, you list possible values this type might get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way to define the datatype:

```
data StringIntPair = StringInt String Int | 
                     IntString Int String 
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Note that I've defined two **constructors** for type `StringIntPair`, and they are `StringInt` and `IntString`.

Now in the definition of `combine`:

```
combine :: StringIntPair -> String
combine (StringInt s i) = s ++ (show i)
combine (IntString i s) = (show i) ++ s
```

I'm using **pattern matching** to match the constructors and select the correct behavior.

Here are some examples of usage:

```
*Main> let y = StringInt "abc" 123
*Main> let z = IntString 789 "a string"
*Main> combine y
"abc123"
*Main> combine z
"789a string"
*Main> :t y
y :: StringIntPair
*Main> :t z
z :: StringIntPair
```

A few things to note about the examples:

- `StringIntPair` is a **type**; doing `:t <expression>` in the interpreter shows the type of an expression
- `StringInt` and `IntString` are **constructors** of the same type
- the vertical bar (`|`) separates constructors
- a well-written function should match each constructor of its argument's types; that's why I've written `combine` with two patterns, one for each constructor

Comment: @wvxvw  Yes you do need to define a constructor!  In `data StringIntPair = StringInt String Int`, **`StringInt String Int`** is a constructor that takes two arguments, a `String` and an `Int` (and in that order!).  I don't know if I completely understand your second question; you may want to post it as a separate question to get a more complete answer.

Comment: A data constructor in Haskell doesn't **do** anything. (It is totally unlike a constructor in C++ or Java). It is just a tag you slap on a bunch of data to distinguish it from other bunches of data. `StringInt "abc" 123` is a `String` and an `Int`, tagged with `StringInt`.

Answer (score 7):

```
data StringIntPair = StringInt String Int
                   | IntString Int String

combine :: StringIntPair -> String
combine (StringInt s i) = s ++ (show i)
combine (IntString i s) = (show i) ++ s
```

So it can be used like that:

```
> combine $ StringInt "asdf" 3
"asdf3"
> combine $ IntString 4 "fasdf"
"4fasdf"
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Haskell is strongly typed, you always know what type a variable has. Additionally, you will never know more. For instance, consider the function `length` that calculates the length of a list. It has the type:

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

That is, it takes a list of arbitrary `a` (although all elements have the same type) and returns and `Int`. The function may never look inside one of the lists node and inspect what is stored in there, since it hasn't and can't get any informations about what type that stuff stored has. This makes Haskell pretty efficient, since, as opposed to typical OOP languages such as Java, no type information has to be stored at runtime.

To make it possible to have different types of variables in one parameter, one can use an *Algebraic Data Type* (ADT). One, that stores either a `String` and an `Int` or an `Int` and a `String` can be defined as:

```
data StringIntPair = StringInt String Int
                   | IntString Int String
```

You can find out about which of the two is taken by *pattern matching* on the parameter. (Notice that you have only one, since both the string and the in are encapsulated in an ADT):

```
combine :: StringIntPair -> String
combine (StringInt str int) = str ++ show int
combine (IntString int str) = show int ++ str
```

Comment: @wvxvw: Function application (the 'space', also called juxtaposition operator) is left-associative and binds most tightly. Otherwise, Haskell allows you to set precendence and associativity of infix operators (via `infix`, `infixr` or `infixl` followed by number from 0 to 9; also called fixity declaration). You can think of function application as `infixl 10`, `++` is `infixr 5`. If you aren't sure, you can use GHCi to find out (type `:i ++`) or use prefix notation (`(++) str (show int)`)

Comment: @wvxvw: If you're looking for a simple rule, just remember that function application binds more tightly than any operator, i.e. `a b # c d` is always `(a b) # (c d)`, no matter which operator `#` is. You shouldn't have to memorize too many precedences besides that.