# Write a generic function with exactly two variations of types of parameters

Tags: generics, haskell

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435526/create-polymorphic-type-int-string-string-int). I think I misunderstood a little bit what type is meant to do in Haskell, so here's, hopefully, a better formulation of the question:

I want to have a function that can be called with exactly two arguments. These arguments must be of different types. For example, one is string, and another is an integer.

Consider this application:

```
combine "100" 500 -- results in 100500
combine 100 "500" -- results in 100500
combine 100 500 -- raises an exception
combine "100" "500" -- raises an exception
```

It is not a problem to write a concrete implementation, it is a problem, however, for me, to give this function a proper signature.

I would be also interested to learn whether there is a solution that is more generic (i.e. doesn't require to specify the concrete types, but only prescribes for the types to be different. So that, for example, you could use this function to "fix" the input to other functions, if it can be fixed by permuting the arguments.

Thank you!

EDIT:

below is an imprecise copy of what I was expecting it to do in Erlang... well, I hope it makes sense, since it should be quite similar...

```
combine([String], Int)->
    io:fwrite("~s~w~n", [[String], Int]);

combine(Int, [String])->
    combine([String], Int).
```

Comment: Since it's an issue with types, you wouldn't want to "raise an exception", you'd want a compile-time error. The difference may sound pedantic, but it's important. In Haskell, we always want compile-time errors if possible. Also, it sounds like you're thinking in Python instead of Haskell :P

Comment: I'd say the right way to do this is to write: `combine :: Integer -> String -> String`. That guarantees it will take exactly one argument of each type. It's simple, it's clear. It doesn't involve any advanced features. What more could you ask for?

Comment: I personally would recommend simply making two functions: `combineStrInt :: String -> Int -> Int` and `combineIntStr :: Int -> String -> Int`. I *would* recommend just one function, and then using `flip` to reverse the order of arguments when needed, but for your example, simply flipping the parameters would not produce the correct result. In practice, you will probably find `flip` useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sjoerd beat me to it, but I prefer my solution so I'll post it anyway.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

module Foo where

class Combinable a b where
  combine :: a -> b -> Int

instance Combinable Int String where
  combine a b = read (show a ++ b)

instance Combinable String Int where
  combine a b = read (a ++ show b)
```

Since this doesn't include a `Combinable a a` instance, trying to use one is a compile-time error rather than a runtime error.

Answer (score 6):

It's not 100% clear to me *why* you want this. One possibility I came up with that others hadn't mentioned is that you simply want order-agnostic function application. This is possible with the "record application" idiom. For example, you might write something like this:

```
data Argument = Argument { name :: String, age :: Int }
instance Default Argument where def = Argument def def

combine Argument { name = n, age = a } = name ++ " is " ++ show age ++ " years old"
```

You can then call it with named arguments:

```
combine def { name = "Daniel", age = 3 }
combine def { age = 3, name = "Daniel" }
```

Names are even just a tad better than checking that the types aren't equal, because you can have multiple arguments with the same type without ambiguity.

```
data Name = Name { first, middle, last :: String }
instance Default Name where def = Name def def def

esquire n@(Name { last = l }) = n { last = l ++ ", Esquire" }
```

Which you can call like these two, for example:

```
esquire def { first = "Daniel", middle = "M.", last = "Wagner" }
esquire def { last = "Wagner", first = "Daniel" }
```

Answer (score 6):

While the other answers are "write a (slightly ugly) class" and "unify the types via an sum type".  I'm going to make a not-very-Haskelly suggestion and remind everyone that Haskell does have dynamic typing if you ask for it.

At run-time, just ASK what the type is and make your operation different for each type.  This can be done using the Data.Typeable module.

For example:

```
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Data

combine :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> b -> Int
combine a b
  | typeOf a == strTy && typeOf b == intTy =
      case (cast a, cast b) of
          (Just str,Just i) -> read $ str ++ show (i :: Int)
  | typeOf a == intTy && typeOf b == strTy =
      case (cast a, cast b) of
          (Just i,Just str) -> read $ show (i :: Int) ++ str
  | otherwise = error "You said you wanted an exception..."
 where
 strTy = typeOf ""
 intTy = typeOf (undefined :: Int)
```

And a test run shows:

```
> combine "100" (500 :: Int)
100500
```

If you want to get rid of the exception then great!  We can clean up the code using the Maybe monad while we're at it:

```
combine2 :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> b -> Maybe Int
combine2 a b
  | typeOf a == strTy && typeOf b == intTy = do
      a' <- cast a
      b' <- cast b
      return $ read $ a' ++ show (b' :: Int)
  | typeOf a == intTy && typeOf b == strTy = do
      a' <- cast a
      b' <- cast b
      return $ read $ show (a' :: Int) ++ b'
  | otherwise = Nothing
 where
 strTy = typeOf ""
 intTy = typeOf (undefined :: Int)
```

And some more output just for the heck of it:

```
> combine2 "500" (5 :: Int)
Just 5005
> combine (5 :: Int) "500"
5500
> combine2 (5 :: Int) "500"
Just 5500
> combine "500" "300"
*** Exception: You said you wanted an exception...
> combine2 "500" "300"
Nothing
```

And that's it!  We can add how ever many of combinations of types we want, just insert your desired operations before the last `otherwise` guard.

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost positive that you cannot do the generic thing you describe.  There's no way in Haskell to express negations of equalities like you describe.

You might be able to do some really dirty hack using `OverlappingInstances` and multi-parameter type classes, which would result in runtime errors instead of compile-time errors, but that'd be really ugly and depressing.

Comment: Actually, you can enforce type inequality in Haskell via multi-parameter type classes/function dependencies/etc and get compile time errors.  "Oleg Already Did It."  A huge amount of type level programming relies on this.  As far as I know this is the only kind of negative constraint that can be enforced.  It is also obviously an unsound violation of the OWS when combined with type families.

Answer (score 3):

The ugly and depressing solution Louis Wasserman mentioned would be something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Combine a b where 
  combine :: a -> b -> String

instance Combine a a where
  combine = error "Types are the same"

instance (Show a, Show b) => Combine a b where
  combine a b = show a ++ show b
```

Comment: You'll _probably_ need OverlappingInstances to make GHC swallow that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Surprisingly you don't. Unless you use it in a situation that _might_ use `combine :: a -> a -> String`. GHC's overlap check is lazy, it doesn't trigger until needed.

Comment: Our answers are essentially the same; the only difference are the instances we chose to define.  Many Haskellers have an aversion to writing large numbers of instance decls (my approach will lead to an explosion of decls if you start adding more types), but IMHO sometimes it is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Another ugly and depressing solution:

```
{-# FlexibleInstances, TypeSynonymInstances #-}

class IntOrString a where
  toString :: a -> String
  typeID :: a -> Int

instance IntOrString String where
  toString s = s
  typeID _ = 0    

instance IntOrString Int where
  toString x = show x
  typeID _ = 1    

combine a b | typeID a + typeID b == 1 = toString a ++ toString b
combine _ _ = error "WTF?!?"

combine "100" (500::Int) --type needed because of monomorphism restriction
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an own data type becouse you can't have undefined types in haskell.

```
data IntAndString = TypeA Int String | TypeB String Int

combine IntAndString -> string
combine TypeA(n s) = show n ++ s
combine TypeB(s n) = s ++ show n
```

combine can eiter be called with

```
combine TypeA(Int String)
```

or

```
combine TypeB(String Int)
```

Comment: Upvoted because I like the solution, but what do you mean that Haskell can't have generic types?

Comment: Well that was wrong by me. Types can be geniric but functions can't be generic

Answer (score 1):

> It is not a problem to write a concrete implementation, it is a
>   problem, however, for me, to give this function a proper signature.

As long as the functions do not have higher ranked types, you don't need to. Haskell will infer the type for you.

That said, I feel what you want does not make much sense in Haskell, where code and data are strictly separated¹ as well as run time and compile time, unlike in Lisp. What would be a use case for `combine`?

¹ Of course, functions are data in a sense, but they are just entirely opaque constants. You cannot manipulate a function at run time.

Comment: That's easy: It doesn't. There is no such thing as multiple dispatch in Haskell.